# Android add multiple fragments to grid layout

Tags: android, gridview

My application loads multiple articles from a database and shows them as some kind of fragment inside a grid view. My problem is to display every fragment loaded inside this grid view. With my current implementation its limited to just one fragment (always the last one added). I think its because the row and column in which the fragment should be added are defined nowhere.

Is there a way to define row and column in this case or at the best populate the grid automatically? I'm stuck here since a while now and couldn't find a solution yet.

Method to load fragments into grid:

```js
   private void loadFragmentsFromArticleList(List<DatabaseArticle> articles){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        grid.removeAllViews();
        for(DatabaseArticle a : articles){
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            CategoryButtonFragment fragment = CategoryButtonFragment.newInstance(a.getName(),"");
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.gridButtons,fragment,null).commit();
        }


    }
```

**Grid XML**

```html
 <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/gridButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/btnDB"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnSearch"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                >

            </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right about that the layout in which the fragments has to added are defined nowhere, if you add fragments after creating the gridview, then you might use fragment transaction like 
fragmentTransaction.add(grid.getViewAtPosition(i).getId(),fragment,null).commit();
then we would have the id's of each individual grid view field and then we can display fragment in that fields.

Comment: I understand the Theory but there is no getViewAtPosition() method fro GridLayout?

Comment: maybe you can use getChildAt() instead of getViewAtPosition, it is inherited method from the parent class of GridLayout i.e. ViewGroup

Comment: Already tried, but doesnt work. However Im using a Linear Layout now wich workarounds my problem. Ill accept you Answer for your effort